# how to code asp.net (.aspx) to show ballon on system tray

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I created a page named discussion_monitoring.aspx for fraud monitoring, impolite wording monitor. When detected, I just want to show balloon on system tray. but I haven't found that code to show balloon on taskbar system tray. Most example code I found is on Windows forms, not webform. 
Environment: ASP.Net 2.0, Windows XP.

Answer (score 7):

You want to show a balloon in the *user's* system tray? You can't do it. A web page doesn't have the level of desktop access (shy of an ActiveX control) necessary to make changes like that.

The closest you can hope to achieve is some kind of notification on the web page itself.

If you want the balloon to appear on the *server's* desktop, you should be able to use the same code that you've seen in a WinForms context. Just import the appropriate WinForms assemblies (System.Windows.Forms, probably System.Drawing), and you're good to go.

Note that it can get hairy, triggering GUI activity on your server from a webapp. You don't want to do things like open a dialog and wait for a response you're never going to get, for instance.

Comment: Thank you, your reply make me clear. again glad to see your reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

As "Michael Petrotta" said, you can't... But here is the Javascript for showing baloon in the page: http://mckay.cshl.edu/balloons.html